# My String Variables are not being Initialized by Double.parseDouble, but only on howMuchMeat and howManyBurgers, not answer

Tags: java, string, double, user-input

I am getting errors on these lines:

```
meat = Double.parseDouble(howMuchMeat);
```

and

```
burgers = Double.parseDouble(howManyBurgers);
```

It says that `howMuchMeat` and `howManyBurgers` are not initialized, how do I initialize them with user inputs?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class HamburgerHelperProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer;
        String howManyBurgers;
        String howMuchMeat;
        double a;
        double burgers, meat;
        double burgers1, meat1;
        
        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I am your hamburger helper! What question do you need answered? "
                + "\nAnswer 1 to find how many burgers can be made from a certain amount of meat, "
                + "\nand 2 to find how much meat is needed to make a specific number of burgers. ");
        a = Double.parseDouble(answer);
        
        if ( a == 1 )
            howManyBurgers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much meat do you have? (Enter in pounds): ");
        burgers = Double.parseDouble(howManyBurgers);
        
        burgers1 = burgers % ( 1 / 4 );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can make " + burgers1 + " burgers.");
        
        if ( a == 2 )
            howMuchMeat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many burgers do you want to make? (Enter whole numbers): ");
        meat = Double.parseDouble(howMuchMeat);
        meat1 = meat * ( 1 / 4 );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need " + meat1 + " pounds of meat to make " + meat + " burgers.");
            
        if ( a != 2 )
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid, try again."); 
                else if ( a != 1 )
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid, try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right after the first `if`, what happens if `a` is not 1?

Comment: `1 / 4` is integer math (not floating point) and is equal to 0.  I think this might be an issue.

Comment: @markspace how would I make the function still work by multiplying the entered input by 1/4?

Comment: Convert to doubles: `1.0 / 4.0`.

Comment: `howMuchMeat` and `howManyBurgers` are initialized, conditionally, by `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`, not by `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: @user207421 how would I rewrite that?